# Error in Front End Product Creation?

Tags: magento-1.7, product, catalog

I have adding product in front end.

I get below error message.

[image]

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`magento`.`catalog_product_entity`, CONSTRAINT
>   `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ATTR_SET_ID_EAV_ATTR_SET_ATTR_SET_ID` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`attribute_set_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attribute_set`
>   (`attribute_set_id`) ON DE)

```
public function saveVirtualNewProduct($wholedata)
{           
        $cats=array();
        foreach($wholedata['category'] as $keycat){
            array_push($cats,$keycat);
        }
        if($wholedata['status']==1 && isset($wholedata['wstoreids']) ){
            $status=1; 
            $stores=$wholedata['wstoreids'];
        }
        else{
            $status=Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_options/product_approval')? 2:1;
            $stores=Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
        }
        $magentoProductModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $magentoProductModel->setData($wholedata);
        $saved=$magentoProductModel->save();
        $lastInserId = $saved->getId();
/* Update  Special from-to Date */
    if($wholedata['special_from_date'] && $wholedata['special_to_date']) 
    {
        //Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($lastInserId);
        $product->setSpecialFromDate($wholedata['special_from_date']);
        $product->setSpecialFromDateIsFormated(true);
        $product->setSpecialToDate($wholedata['special_to_date']);
        $product->setSpecialToDateIsFormated(true);
        $product->save();
    }
/* Update  Special from-to Date */

        $magentoProductModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($saved->getId());
        $baseCurrencyCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseCurrencyCode();
        $currentCurrencyCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
        $allowedCurrencies = Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->getConfigAllowCurrencies(); 
        $rates = Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->getCurrencyRates($baseCurrencyCode, array_values($allowedCurrencies));

        if($wholedata['special_price']){
            $special_price = $wholedata['special_price']/$rates[$currentCurrencyCode];
            $magentoProductModel->setSpecialPrice($special_price);
        }

        $price = $wholedata['price']/$rates[$currentCurrencyCode];
        $magentoProductModel->setPrice($price);
        $magentoProductModel->setStoresIds(array($stores));
        $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
        $magentoProductModel->setWebsiteIds(array(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load( $storeId )->getWebsiteId()));
        $magentoProductModel->setCategoryIds($cats);
        $magentoProductModel->setStatus($status);
        $saved=$magentoProductModel->save();
        $lastId = $saved->getId();
        $this->_saveStock($lastId,$wholedata['stock'],$wholedata['is_in_stock']);

        $wholedata['id'] = $lastId;

        $collection1=Mage::getModel('marketplace/product');
        $collection1->setmageproductid($lastId);
        $collection1->setuserid($wholedata['userid']);
        $collection1->setstatus($status);
        $collection1->save();

        if($wholedata['type_id']=='virtual'){
        if((isset($_FILES) && count($_FILES) > 0) && !isset($wholedata['csv'])){
                if (!is_dir(Mage::getBaseDir().'/media/marketplace/')){
                mkdir(Mage::getBaseDir().'/media/marketplace/', 0755);
                }
                    if (!is_dir(Mage::getBaseDir().'/media/marketplace/'.$lastId)){
                    mkdir(Mage::getBaseDir().'/media/marketplace/'.$lastId, 0755);
                    }
                foreach($_FILES as $image){
                    $imagesdir = Mage::getBaseDir().'/media/marketplace/'.$lastId.'/';
                    $filename = $image['name'];                 
                    move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'],$imagesdir.$filename);    
                    }
                $this->_addImages($lastId,$wholedata['defaultimage']);
            }
        }
        return $lastId;     
    }
```

Please any one help me

Thanks.

Comment: do you have any setup scripts running? just the error message alone it will be hard to find out what is causing it.

Comment: whats the code on line 18 in your MarketplaceaccountController.php?

Comment: Also a little suggestion, I guess you don't need to load the same product again and again to update. you can update and save using the model `$magentoProductModel` initialized at the start of the function. This will reduce the overhead.

Comment: Please check this [great debugging tutorial](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store/429#429) and report back.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create a product without the `attribute_set_id` or with a value for that column that does not exist in the attribute sets value.

and on a side note...you use too many `save` calls to save a single product.
Build one big array with attributes and assign it to the product model, then save only once.